# Video path from uri returns null in Moto G

Tags: android

This is my code and it returns null when I select any video in Moto G.

```
public String getRealPathForVideo(Uri uri) {
    if( uri == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: It should be return real path. It's working proper in other devices.

Comment: I have this URI:  content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A1520